# Add Error Message on Opportunity

Tags: trigger

I would Like to add an error message on opportunity if Opportunity has openActivities And someone tries to modify it. It should not allow opportunity modification unless and until openActivities = 0. I have below code which gives Open Activity count?

```
            Integer count = 0;
            String ids = '';
            //Opportunity opp = null;
            List<Opportunity> olist = [SELECT StageName, Id, (SELECT Id, Status FROM OpenActivities), Probability FROM Opportunity
                                       WHERE Id  =:Trigger.New];
            for (Opportunity o : olist) 
            {
                for (OpenActivity a : o.OpenActivities) 
                {

                    count++;
                    System.debug(a.Status);
                    System.debug('Count = '+count);
                    //ids = o.id;

                }   

            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//query on opportunity and also the one opne activity if present 
List<Opportunity> olist = [SELECT StageName, Id, 
                                 (SELECT Id, Status FROM OpenActivities  
                                   WHERE Isclosed != true LIMIT 1), 
                                  Probability
                           FROM Opportunity
                           WHERE Id  =:Trigger.New];
for (Opportunity o : olist) 
{
    Boolean isOpenActivity = false;
    //check if a open activity present then add error message to opportunity record
    for (OpenActivity a : o.OpenActivities) 
    {
        isOpenActivity = true;
    }   
    if(isOpenActivity)
    {
        Trigger.NewMap.get(o.Id).addError('Open Activity is present');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot bro.. can u plz tell me when to go for map and when to go for list in trigger...

Comment: In above Code i wouild like to auto update the Opportunity StageName and Probability if there are no OpenActivies for an Opportunity.

Suppose, If Probability is 5 and there is no openActivity then Probability should change from 5 to 30, if there is openActivity it show Error message which done in above code. but how to update that as per above condition..

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of the `size()` attribute of `list` here. So instead of looping through `o.OpenActivities`, you can use `o.OpenActivities.size()` to determine whether or not the Opportunity have any open Activities

```
if(o.OpenActivities.size() > 0)
```

So your final code should be

```
Integer count = 0;
        String ids = '';
        //Opportunity opp = null;
        List<Opportunity> olist = [SELECT StageName, Id, (SELECT Id, Status FROM          OpenActivities), Probability
                                   FROM Opportunity
                                   WHERE Id  =:Trigger.New];
        for (Opportunity o : olist) 
        {
            if(o.OpenActivities.size() > 0) {
                Trigger.NewMap.get(o.Id).addError('You cannot modify an Opportunity which have Open Activities associated to it.');
            }
        }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: since you are not added any filter in subquery OpenActivities and you are checking  `o.OpenActivities.size()` in this case if OpenActivities size is greater than 200 then you will get error like *'First error: Aggregate query has too many rows for direct assignment, use FOR loop'. *